# Binding adapter - cannot find setter for LiveData variable in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-binding-adapter

I'm trying to implement RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and I'm stuck.
I'm receiving error:

```
If a binding adapter provides the setter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
Open File"
```

When I'm trying to compile. "Open file" provides me to xml recycler view declaration.

This is my BindingAdapter:

```
    @BindingAdapter("listData")
    fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                         data: List<MarsPropertyData>?) {
        val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as PhotoGridAdapter
        adapter.submitList(data)
    }
```

How I'm calling the above:

```
      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/photos_grid"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layoutManager=
                "androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="2"
            tools:itemCount="16"
            tools:listitem="@layout/grid_view_item"
            app:listData="@{viewModel.properties}"
            />
```

And this is my properties variable:

```
val properties: LiveData<List<MarsPropertyData>>
```

I'm understand that IDE complains about data types, my `properties` var it is `LiveData<List<MarsPropertyData>>` and inside `BindingAdapter` there's just normal List, but I saw example from google in which logic was made in same way and it worked fine.

Yes, I have added `'kotlin-kapt'` plugin, I have another BindingAdapter which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem while working on a google codelab whose setup is very similar to yours.
In my case, I inadvertently defined the "bindRecyclerView" bindingAdapter function within the curly braces of a previous bindingAdapter function. This resulted in the "bindRecyclerView" function being eclipsed by the previous function and hence its setter cannot be seen from other files. When I removed it from within the previous function, everything worked fine.